# How to change chart.y_axis category to number

Tags: python, openpyxl

All I'm trying to change the x_axis category to the number because the chart keep show like below.
this is my code in python using openpyxl

```
        chart = LineChart()
        chart.title = f'{key}-{date()}'
        chart.height = 14
        chart.width = 30
        chart.y_axis = Typed(expected_type=NumericAxis)
        data = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_row=y, max_col=z)
        cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=y, max_col=1)
        chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
        chart.set_categories(cats)
        ws.add_chart(chart, "B2")
        writer.save()
```

(What i want is to show number like" 50000000" instead of "5E+09")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkKEg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jF35K.png)

Comment: Hi All, i manage to solved by changeing the cell format to number         df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=key)
        y = len(x.index)
        z = len(x.columns) + 1
        ws = writer.sheets[key]
        for i in range(1, z):
            for e in range(1, y):
                cell = ws.cell(e, i)
                cell.number_format = '0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: -to change all cell format  to number

```
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='`sheets name`')
    y = len(df.index)
    z = len(df.columns)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('`filename`', engine='openpyxl')
    ws = writer.sheets['`sheets name`']
    for i in range(1, z):
        for e in range(1, y):
            cell = ws.cell(e, i)
            cell.number_format = '0'
```